# How to add members to workspace(Library) in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning-community, lightning-bolt

I'm trying to add users into the workspace as a contentworkspacemember through apex.
Suppose a current user is trying to create a content,

1.I need to check weather the current user has the permission to manage Salesforce CRM content.
2.Then,If user is not a member in that workspace,need to add the user.

I tried developing the below code,sorry for the bad coding!
Could anyone help me out here.

```
  Id idContentWorkspace = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Test' LIMIT 1].Id;

list<ContentWorkspaceMember> ContentWorkspaceMemberadd = new list<ContentWorkspaceMember>();
Id Userid = UserInfo.getUserId();
for(ContentWorkspaceMember iterator : [SELECT ContentWorkspaceId,ContentWorkspacePermissionId FROM ContentWorkspaceMember 
                                        WHERE ContentWorkspaceid =:idContentWorkspace]) {
    ContentWorkspaceMemberadd.add(new ContentWorkspaceMember(ContentWorkspaceId = iterator.ContentWorkspaceId,
    ContentWorkspacePermissionId=iterator.ContentWorkspacePermissionId,MemberId=Userid));
}

if(!ContentWorkspaceMemberadd.isEmpty() && ContentWorkspaceMemberadd != null) {
    Database.upsert(ContentWorkspaceMemberadd, false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```java
Id Userid = UserInfo.getUserId();
List<ContentWorkspace> contentWorkSpaces = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ContentWorkspace];
List<ContentWorkspaceMember> ContentWorkspaceMemberadd = new List<ContentWorkspaceMember>();
for (ContentWorkspaceMember iterator : [
        SELECT
                ContentWorkspaceId,
                ContentWorkspacePermissionId
        FROM ContentWorkspaceMember
        WHERE ContentWorkspaceId IN:contentWorkSpaces
]) {
    ContentWorkspaceMemberadd.add(
            new ContentWorkspaceMember(
                    ContentWorkspaceId = iterator.ContentWorkspaceId,
                    ContentWorkspacePermissionId = iterator.ContentWorkspacePermissionId,
                    MemberId = Userid)
    );
}
if (!ContentWorkspaceMemberadd.isEmpty() && ContentWorkspaceMemberadd != null) {
    Database.upsert(ContentWorkspaceMemberadd, false);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post Code only Answers. Instead, provide an explanation to help the OP understand what was wrong with their original code and how your solution addresses the problem.